# Got FileExistsError after successfully renaming a file using OS module

Tags: python, random, operating-system, rename

So I am trying to rename all the files with `"%"` in their filename in every folder in "img". The code below works. It finds files with `"%"` in their name and renames them. However, after renaming them, the `FileExistsError` shows.

```
    import string, random, os
    
    length = 40
    combination = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
    result_str = "".join(random.choice(combination) for i in range(length))
    
    for folder in os.listdir("./static/img/"):
        for folder_ in os.listdir(f"./static/img/{folder}"):
            for files_ in os.listdir(f"./static/img/{folder}/{folder_}"):
                if "%" in files_:
                    print(f"./static/img/{folder}/{folder_}/{files_}")
                    os.rename(f"./static/img/{folder}/{folder_}/{files_}", f"./static/img/{folder}/{folder_}/{result_str}.jpg")
                    print("Changed Filename")
```

I've tried `os.remove` before the rename like what was suggested in another post, but it removes the file before it can even be renamed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The random string generated once before the loop, so it renames to the same name, it should be inside the loop so for every rename there would be a (probably) unique name:

```
import string, random, os

length = 40
combination = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits

for folder in os.listdir("./static/img/"):
    for folder_ in os.listdir(f"./static/img/{folder}"):
        for files_ in os.listdir(f"./static/img/{folder}/{folder_}"):
            if "%" in files_:
                result_str = "".join(random.choice(combination) for i in range(length))
                print(f"./static/img/{folder}/{folder_}/{files_}")
                os.rename(f"./static/img/{folder}/{folder_}/{files_}", f"./static/img/{folder}/{folder_}/{result_str}.jpg")
                print("Changed Filename")
```